# How to show a category list made by generic views in multiple pages?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views, django-1.6

I'm trying to build my own Blog app with Django 1.6. I've generated a category list by generic views like this:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^categories/?$', views.ListView.as_view(model=Category), name='categories'),
```

**category_list.html**

```
   <h3>Categories</h3>
   {% for category in object_list %}
     <ul>
       <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
     </ul>
   {% endfor %}
```

all categories are now listed at `/categories`.

My problem is when I add it to `base.html` or `index.html` file, output changes to `article.title` not `category.title` How can I add this Category list to other pages such as Index or Article?
Here's my complete views.py file:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from blog.models import Article, Category

class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:10]

class ArticleView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'blog/article.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It renders `article.title` because `object_list` points into article view context, you cannot include isolated view into another view.

I think the cleanest way would be to create a mixin class for categories context and add it to each view, that needs to render it.

Something like this:

```
class CategoryMixin(object):
    def get_categories(self):
        return Category.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = self.get_categories()
        return context
```

then add it to the view class:

```
class IndexView(CategoryMixin, ListView):
    ...
```

and also include `category_list.html` inside each template, passing the context variable (this way you have isolated variable names):

```
{% include "category_list.html" with object_list=categories only %}
```